# Firefox window.open("about:blank") doesn't open blank tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, window.open

I'm trying to open new window with injected javascript code.
Everything works fine in Chrome, but Firefox doesn't open about:blank tab, but only a page with same href and injected script. I need this tab to be perfectly blank, not a copy of current tab. Here is my example code that i'm using:

```
var x = window.open('about:blank');
x.document.write('<script>console.log("hello injected world")</script>');
```

Comment: Firefox opens a new blank page for me, as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that href is about:blank and if you open inspector you have empty html document? Also have you written this code in console or directly in page? Because i think that if you write this in console everything works fine

Comment: If it works fine in console, there might be something weird happening in your page that causes different browser behavior, as `window.open()` is one of the most standard things I can think of.

Comment: Actually even in w3schools example (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open) when you use my code in myFunction() it opens same page, but if you don't use x.document.write it opens about:blank page. This is a strange behaviour for me.

Comment: window.open() will open a new tab. no issues. it is working in fire fox also

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do something like `window.open('blank.html');` and add a `blank.html` file to your project that looks like this for example:

```
<html></html>
```

Comment: Because I don't want to use same domain or any files from server. The point of my work is a work around for some security policy in my project.

Comment: Understand. I guess your FF is up to date / stable

Comment: Yes, i've tried at 45.9.0esr, latest esr and latest firefox version. Same behaviour everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try with empty string "" instead of "about:blank".

```
var x = window.open("");
x.document.write('<script>console.log("hello injected world")</script>');
```

It will work in both Chrome and Firefox, but it depends your browser is not blocking pop ups

Comment: I tried in firefox. Are you sure your browser is not blocking pop ups?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that even if it opens this window it is not truely blank.

Comment: What do you mean with "truely blank"?

Comment: No html inside, no href to my original page, just about:blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Iframe

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write('<iframe width="100%" height="100%"  srcdoc="<html></html>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

Might help you out

Comment: This might actually work, I will try your idea immediately. Thank you for your answer

Comment: unfortunately same behaviour :(